# Снёс настройки в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Хотел решить проблему с подсказками, установил дополнительный плагин из этой статьи https://github.com/dmarcotte/idea-handlebars/issues/84

> Hey @hawkin29, it looks like the plugin isn't enabled (which is why your editor doesn't know how to interpret your example). Checking the following should get you up and running:
>   check Preferences->Plugins and make sure you have the "Handlebars/Mustache" plugin installed
>   check Preferences->File Types and make sure that a pattern which matches your template file is associated with the plugin (for instance, if your filename is "myfile.hbs", then ensure that "*.hbs" is listed for Handlebars/Mustache)
>   Looking forward to getting you all fixed up, so please let me know if that works. If not, we'll try something else!

Единственный косяк, что, когда я "добавлял" расширение .php , то его PHP не было в выпадающем окне, поэтому я по глупости просто вбил в первую строку "*.php", что, естественно, не дало результата. Затем я удалил эту строку и снёс плагин, но все пошло  совсем не так, как я ожидал, и  теперь всё отображается совсем криво. Помогите, пожалуйста. [image: Скриншот проблемы]

Comment: У вас сейчас расширение `*.php` ассоциировано с текстовыми файлами. Вам нужно добавить `*.php` в список паттернов, зарегистрированных для типа PHP

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в

> File > Settings > Editor > File Types

Справа вверху в `Recognized File Types` выберите `PHP` а внизу, в `Registered Patterns` добавьте `*.php`

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!